# Left align elements of horizontal list

Tags: html, css

I have a list that I am using as a horizontal timeline. However, I am having trouble trying to left align the list, so that the first element is flush left with left side of the scrollbar. I know part of the problem is that I have a set `margin-left`, I need some way to put space in between list elements (removing `margin-left` pushes the first element further to the left, but not all the way to be flush with the left side of the scrollbar.

```css
.navbar {
 margin-bottom:0px;
}

.jumbotron {
 margin-bottom:0px;
}

#timeline {
 list-style:none;
 white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:auto;
}

#timeline li {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:1.5%;
 border:1px solid #d1d2d3;
 margin-left:2%;
 margin-bottom:2%;
 margin-top:2%;
 text-align:center;
}

#timeline li h3, #timeline li em {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>My Website</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="styles.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
  
 <div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>My Name</h1>
 </div>
 
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>What I've Been Up To</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <!--Timeline-->
  <div class="row" style="overflow:auto">
   <ul id="timeline">
    <li>
     <h3>Graduated from College</h3>
     <em>May 24, 2012</em>
    </li>
    
    <li>
     <h3>Started my first job</h3>
     <em>June 30, 2012</em>
    </li>
    
    <li>
     <h3>Started my second job</h3>
     <em>April 3, 2014</em>
    </li>
    
    <li>
     <h3>Bought a house!</h3>
     <em>August 12, 2015</em>
    </li>
    
    <li>
     <h3>Got married</h3>
     <em>June 3, 2016</em>
    </li>
    
    <li>
     <h3>First child born</h3>
     <em>May 1, 2017</em>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <footer>
 <p> Copyright &copy;
  <!--Script displays the current year-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var d = new Date()
  document.write(d.getFullYear())
  </script>
 </p>
 </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You mean the horizontal `li` as vertical or contents of `li` to be aligned left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you learn how to use your Browser's developer console.  A quick inspection of this revealed that the `#timeline` element has 40px of `padding-left`.

I removed that padding, and altered your `margin-left` on the timeline items so that it only puts margin between elements.  I did this by using the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
#timeline li + li {
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

And - as a side-note, `0px` is redundant / not necessary, as `0` is unitless, you can simply use `0` in values (such as `margin-bottom: 0;`)

Here's your snippet, modified to work properly:

```css
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#timeline {
    list-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
}

#timeline li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1.5%;
    border: 1px solid #d1d2d3;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}

#timeline li + li {
 margin-left: 2%;
 }

#timeline li h3, 
#timeline li em {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>My Website</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="styles.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
  
 <div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>My Name</h1>
 </div>
 
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>What I've Been Up To</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <!--Timeline-->
  <div class="row" style="overflow:auto">
   <ul id="timeline">
    <li>
     <h3>Graduated from College</h3>
     <em>May 24, 2012</em>
    </li>
    
    <li>
     <h3>Started my first job</h3>
     <em>June 30, 2012</em>
    </li>
    
    <li>
     <h3>Started my second job</h3>
     <em>April 3, 2014</em>
    </li>
    
    <li>
     <h3>Bought a house!</h3>
     <em>August 12, 2015</em>
    </li>
    
    <li>
     <h3>Got married</h3>
     <em>June 3, 2016</em>
    </li>
    
    <li>
     <h3>First child born</h3>
     <em>May 1, 2017</em>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <footer>
 <p> Copyright &copy;
  <!--Script displays the current year-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var d = new Date()
  document.write(d.getFullYear())
  </script>
 </p>
 </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will start looking into the Chrome developer tools more. After you suggested doing so, I was able to figure out how to examine the different elements and saw the padding.

Comment: I'd like to note that the padding came from default browser styling for a `ul`. It is often quit desirable to reset browser styles, especially for ordered and un-ordered lists.

Answer (score 1):

You have everything there except you omitted `padding-left:0px;` in the timeline id!

Well done you, looks great!

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#timeline {
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-left: 0px; 
}

#timeline li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.5%;
  border: 1px solid #d1d2d3;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  text-align: center;
}

#timeline li h3,
#timeline li em {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Website</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>My Name</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>What I've Been Up To</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Timeline-->
    <div class="row" style="overflow:auto">
      <ul id="timeline">
        <li>
          <h3>Graduated from College</h3>
          <em>May 24, 2012</em>
        </li>

        <li>
          <h3>Started my first job</h3>
          <em>June 30, 2012</em>
        </li>

        <li>
          <h3>Started my second job</h3>
          <em>April 3, 2014</em>
        </li>

        <li>
          <h3>Bought a house!</h3>
          <em>August 12, 2015</em>
        </li>

        <li>
          <h3>Got married</h3>
          <em>June 3, 2016</em>
        </li>

        <li>
          <h3>First child born</h3>
          <em>May 1, 2017</em>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <p> Copyright &copy;
      <!--Script displays the current year-->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var d = new Date()
        document.write(d.getFullYear())
      </script>
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get those Li's really stuck to the left hand-side of your element you need remove the padding and margin from the UL first, then on the Li's apply a margin-right rather than left.

```
#timeline {
    list-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#timeline li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1.5%;
    border: 1px solid #d1d2d3;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is the `margin-left` on the list element, yes. You can remove that for the first one like so: `#timeline li:first-child { margin-left: 0; }`. Additionally, the `ul` itself has padding to the left by default, which you can remove like so: `#timeline { padding-left: 0; }`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in this to the css:

```
#timeline li:first-child {
  margin-left:0
}
```

and change this css for the timeline element:

```
#timeline {
    list-style:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

thats it!